how use Http client (post request)
In pure php, I made a query of the following type:
$post_data = http_build_query([
    'integrationModule' => json_encode($body)
]);

$header = [
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-API-KEY: ' . $this->apiKey
];

$opts = [
    'http' => [
        'method'        => 'POST',
        'ignore_errors' => true,
        'header'        => $header,
        'content'       => $post_data
    ]
];
$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);
$resp  = file_get_contents($this->url . '/api/v5/integration-modules/module-name/edit', false, $ctx);
$data = json_decode($resp, true);

I received Success in response
I want to rewrite this to Http-client in Laravel:
$res = Http::withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-API-KEY' => $this->apiKey,
    ])
    ->post(
        $this->url . '/api/v5/integration-modules/module-name/edit',
        [
            'integrationModule' => json_encode($body)
        ]
    );

but in response I get:
"success" => false  
"errorMsg" => "Parameter 'integrationModule' is missing"

What is my mistake?

I checked with AI, and it suggested assembling the postdata like this:
$postData = http_build_query([     'integrationModule' => json_encode($body) ]);
And send $postData as second argument to post() function.
This has to be done due to changing the content type header

@Techno - Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

@DarkBee Thanks for letting me know, good thing i did it the other way around: Looked at an AI answer and reworded it myself :)

Good thing its not generated nor reworded with AI ;)

"checked with AI, and it suggested assembling the postdata like this:" ...
